# Elasticsearch Kubernetes pod - can't connect to port 9300

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes

I am trying to connect my elastic search pod, to ports 9200 and 9300. When I go to:

`http://localhost:$IP_FROM_KUBECTL_PROXY(usually 8001)/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/$POD_NAME/proxy/`

I see the following error:

```
Error: 'net/http: HTTP/1.x transport connection broken: malformed HTTP status code "is"'
Trying to reach: 'http://172.17.0.5:9300/'
```

What I did is, running :

```
kubectl run elasticsearch --image=elasticsearch:6.6.1 -labels="elasticsearch" --env="discovery.type=single-node" --port=9200 --port=9300
```

and running the following service:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch
spec:
  selector:
    host: elasticsearch
    subdomain: for-kibana
    app: elasticsearch
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    name: serving
    port: 9200
    targetPort: 9200
  - protocol: TCP
    name: node2node
    port: 9300
    targetPort: 9300
```

It's weird, because when I just use port 9200, all works, but when I run with 9300, its fail.

Answer (score 5):

Port 9300 is binary protocol (not http) and used for node communication. Only port 9200 exposed the Rest Api

From the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_talking_to_elasticsearch.html):

> Both Java clients talk to the cluster over port 9300, using the native
>   Elasticsearch transport protocol. The nodes in the cluster also
>   communicate with each other over port 9300. If this port is not open,
>   your nodes will not be able to form a cluster.

Comment: Do I need port 9300 to talk to kibana? If so, how can I add it?

Comment: I think that you will need to run a different kibana docker. see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/docker.html  and https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/6.6/settings.html